# importing Alamofire into at manually imported SDK

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I am trying to (manually) install an openAPI SDK.
I have added the code by making it a Cocoa Touch Framework inside my Xcode project.

Unfortunately the SDK relies on `Alamofire` i have installed it via Cocoapods, but the module is not recognized by the framework.

Any idea how to link them?

Comment: What error message is throwing?

Comment: no such module 'Alamofire'

Comment: press `command+shift+k` and then build again. Maybe it will work.

Comment: it does not, unfortunately. But now my frameworks have turned red - as in cant be found

Comment: Quit your Xcode and open again the project. It sometimes shows the error `no such module 'Alamofire'` when installing it via cocoa pods.

Comment: no chance :/ I just reinstalled all pods. Now I get an error in all of them saying 'Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code'

Comment: do you have `use_frameworks!` in your podfile?